# How to design/word Dynamic Programming sub problems?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, dynamic-programming

I am trying out the bottom up dynamic programming method and I have a few problems with it.

I have learnt to arrive at the required solution by storing previously computed values in either a 1D or 2D array and referring to them when necessary. The problem is I am not able to backtrack using the values stored in my array.

For example, if the problem is the classic 'Longest Subsequence' problem, I can arrive at the value of the longest subsequence, but I am not able to backtrack through the stored values and find what letters/digits appear in the subsequence.

I have gone through a lot of university course tutorials and youtube tutorials, but nobody seems to explain how a person can 'word' the subproblem correctly.

Does anybody have tips on how to craft the subproblems and maintain array values so that backtracking possible and easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to keep a second array with the same dimensions as the first, and call it your `index` array, and use it to track the location of the element that contributed to your choice.

So in a 2d example:
Let`A` be the standard dynamic programming array
Let `I` be the index array

If the value `A[x,y]` is decided by `A[x0,y0]`, then `I[x,y]=(x0,y0)`.

When trying to backtrack from `A[i,j]`, access `I[i,j]` to find the next element in the backtrack chain.

You can use default values for the array `I` so you know when you have reached the end of the chain.

Comment: thank you for the tip. Will definitely try this out!

Comment: No problem! This worked for me during my dynamic programming use.

Comment: @SriHariVignesh If this solution helped you, can you mark it as the answer to close the question?

Comment: I thought my question had no definitive 'real' answers. So I wanted to wait for other people to pitch in their ideas and tips.

Comment: Absolutely, good to hear other opinions.